# Subtotal IF formula

Tags: google-sheets

Sorry if this is a real basic question - But I'm not having any luck at all.

How would I subtotal only cells within the G column that meet the following requirements based on their row:

Contain the word 'test' in column A

Contain the date '01/01/2023' in column C

I've tried using SUMIF, but not sure how to incorporate the 'Subtotal 109'?

Comment: Are you using `subtotal` Fx in this scenario to exclude the hidden rows data during filtering?!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The SUBTOTAL function only operates on ranges. To accomplish what you're asking for you have to first filter the data in a separate range and then run SUBTOTAL.